# ASP.Net - C# - Passing Page as parameter

Tags: asp.net, reference

I have a website. from each page of website I want to call a function which will receive a parameter of type Page. Each page will pass reference of itself to that function.

That function will hide and show some control on that page based on some logic.

Now I am not sure how to pass the page parameter. If I pass "`this`", I am unable to find any controls which I want to hide or show. This is my function

```
public static void Implement(string pageName, Page objPage)
    {
        if (pageName == "MANAGEMENT")
        {
            HyperLink obj = (HyperLink) objPage.FindControl("hlSave");
            if (obj != null)
            {
                obj.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

but `objPage.FindControl("hlSave");` always returns null

Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: @Knvn, no i'm not using Master Pages

Comment: even though you are not using master page, the `FindControlRecursive` method that I have provided has to find it(with poor performance). Did you checked it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `master page` then that might causing `FindControl` to return `null`. In that case you can use:

```
HyperLink obj = (HyperLink)objPage.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderID").FindControl("hlSave");
```

or you can recursively find `hlSave` using below method:

```
    public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id)
    {
        if (Root.ID == Id)
            return Root;

        foreach (Control Ctl in Root.Controls)
        {
            Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(Ctl, Id);
            if (FoundCtl != null)
                return FoundCtl;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

you can use it like:

```
HyperLink obj = (HyperLink)FindControlRecursive(objPage, "hlSave");
```